# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 25 and input n_features is 76

Tags: python

I am using MLPClassifier to train my model and then will be deploying it in an app/Website.But I am getting this error as the input from user will not be fixed ,using get_dummies is throwing an error.here is my code.
Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_csv("nikita_attrition.csv")
df_o= pd.read_csv("nikita_attrition.csv")
print(df.info())
df=df.drop('StandardHours',axis=1)
df_o=df_o.drop('StandardHours',axis=1)
```

```
features_in = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Education','JobSatisfaction', 'WorkLifeBalance', 'EnvironmentSatisfaction', 'StockOptionLevel', 'JobInvolvement', 'PerformanceRating', 'JobLevel'], dummy_na=False)
features_out=pd.get_dummies(df_o,columns=['Attrition'],drop_first=True)
features_in.shape
```

I am taking input from user via App and coverting it into dataframe and then giving it to my model which is used through pickel file but I am getting the above error.

Comment: could you elaborate more upon the total number of features in your dataset, and number of features you trained your model upon?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! now I dropped some columns I am having 49 features for training model but actually the file which will be uploaded will contain only 25 features I am giving template for the file I got one solution that I can handle this at the APP's programming, but now as I am checking the accuracy after dropping some columns I am not getting any difference in accuracy  , I want my recall value more , right now its just 0.5 can you suggest how can I improve the model accuracy and recall value more